# Animated Splash Screen in Flash Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, flexbuilder

I'm trying to set up an animated splash screen in flash builder 4.6, but cant seem to get it to work with a gif. Basically I just want my splash to show to images then goto the login. how would I achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: by default gifs do not get animated inside flash/flex. You need an external lib which will handle that. I recommend you to google.

Answer (score 0):

You need a gif loader for gifs, or create a sprite sheet and manually make the animation from it, in code. You should go to [www.kirupa.com](http://www.kirupa.com). There are tutorials on this there, in as 3.

Comment: Thanks I ended up just making a transition through catalyst and then putting it into flash builder.